# How to select an element without selecting child elements

Tags: jquery

I want to select an element with query while omitting one but not all of its children:

```
<div class="parent-that-I-want-jquery-to-find">
  <div class="child-I-want-omitted">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="child-I-dont-want-omitted">
    <p></p>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Do you want the resulting jQuery matched set to contain just the parent, just the child-you-want, both, or something else?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Uh? If you select an element then you are selecting only the element, not its children. You *might* be looking for the for the `:not` selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.parent-that-I-want-jquery-to-find').children().not('.child-I-want-omitted');
```