# JQuery selector with both a selector and not-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following JQuery function:

```
$('article.node--article p, .video-title').highlightWordAndScroll({
    words       : search_word,
    tag         : '<span class="found_keyword">',
    closingtag  : '</span>',
}, scrollTo);
```

which basically wraps a class `found_keyword` around the `search_word`. Nothing more.
But between some `<p>` tags are `<img>`tags. And because the `found_keyword` class is wrapped around the image name, the image isn't rendered properly anymore.

```
<p class="rtecenter">
   <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/userfiles/logo_&lt;span class=" found_keyword"="">foto.jpg" style="height:87px; width:332px"&gt;
</p>
```

And so, the image-rendering is broken. Is there a way to exclude the image tag in the JQuery selector?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the link. I've tried with following code, but no luck there...

```
$('article.node--article p, .video-title').children().not("img").highlightWordAndScroll({
    words       : search_word,
    tag         : '<span class="found_keyword">',
    closingtag  : '</span>',
}, scrollTo);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select an element without selecting child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574832/how-to-select-an-element-without-selecting-child-elements)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do more Jquery to remove the classes after, but for img tags only

Comment: Hmm, not a bad idea... Any hulp on how to do this the shortest way possible?

Comment: $( "p > img" ).removeClass( "found_keyword" )